# Preview Jupyter Notebooks in Ubuntu

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Peeking at Jupyter notebooks is a long process, need to `cd` to the file location and need to run `jupyter notebook` to start the server and get things done, but I don't need to edit or work with it. Is there any other possible way to just take a look at notebooks quickly?

Looking for the Linux equivalent of this [tuxu/nbviewer](https://github.com/tuxu/nbviewer-app)

PS: Already know about a Firefox extension but it is broken now.

Comment: Seeking a software or libraries is considered off topic for Stackoverflow, but no, you don't need to cd anywhere. You can set the notebook directory with that command directly

Comment: I got numerous notebooks scattered across different folders, for a purpose, and as far as I know Stackoverflow helps as long as there is some effort from the person who has posted the question. I am not searching for a software or a library, I am asking if anybody else has an easier workaround for it. Please stop spreading toxicity in a community, where people are always trying to learn.

Comment: "Looking for the Linux equivalent of this tuxu/nbviewer" sounds like you're asking for a library or other software to me... I'm telling you the sites rules as defined in [help], not spreading anything

Comment: Apologies, read the guidelines in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ipynb`(s) cannot be previewed, instead if you convert your notebook to `html`, it can be previewed right away, use `jupyter nbconvert --to html yournotebook.ipynb` and preview it with a double click. You can write your own code to automate this since you are using python, or you can install this [nb-viewer](https://github.com/jithu7432/nb-viewer) which basically lets you open `.ipynb`(s) in your linux machine with a double-click.